# Starting out ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting to learn ASP.MVC3. From the code and tutorial , it seems that it is using Enity to LINQ for controller code generated.Some of the code i am not able to understand which is generated in controller. 
Which topics is to be read to understand ...
ie LINQ , Entity Framework , MVC3 Helper Methods . etc. . Which is best link from where i can get this doc.?

Answer (score 2):

Start with: [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 1):

To understand asp.net mvc concepts (controller, helpers, views) :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs

A good set of videos are here

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos

After you've got some concepts..you can try [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx)

Comment: But this does not explain controller generated code

Answer (score 1):

See MVC FAQ, 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/10/15/mvc-faq.aspx

Comment: I know bit of ASP.NET and understand MVC , is it necessary to go through ASP.NET MVC2 ...